Getting 401 unauthorized for Laravel11 sanctum
i use Laravel11 sanctum session (not token)
Login and logout (endpoints) are working correctly when called from postman
but when I call  other api end points it  gives me 401 unauthorized
Could someone help me out please?aaa

Solved,just add 
->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
$middleware->statefulApi();
  $middleware->api([
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidateCsrfToken::class,
        ]);
    })


In you bootsrap/app.php you can do this:

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->statefulApi();

        $middleware->trustProxies(
            at: null,
            headers: Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR |
                Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST |
                Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT |
                Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO |
                Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB
        );
    })->create();

What is going on here?

$middleware->statefulApi() Indicate that Sanctum's frontend state middleware should be enabled, this will allow you to access your API from your first-party SPA or other origins.

$middleware->trustProxies() Allows you to configure the trusted proxies for your API.


Then in your frontend request you have to pass in the authentication token generated by sanctum if you're trying to access an endpoint that is behind a login wall.
If you use Axios you can do something like this:
import axios from "axios";

const token = '12|121212.....'

axios.get('/account', {
   headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
   }
})
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.data);
  });


Thank you for your response but still the same problem :(

@marwenkhefacha update your question to include what the route you're trying to access looks like and any other code examples that would help make your challenge more understandable.
